# What is the ServiceStack.Text-equivalent of Json.NET Converters, for example when applied to NodaTime types?

Tags: c#, serialization, servicestack, nodatime, servicestack-text

How can I control the serialization/deserialization of custom types (such as `NodaTime.LocalDateTime`) with ServiceStack.Text?

Json.NET provides [`Converters`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)  for this, so that each time a class contains a custom type, the corresponding custom serializer/deserializer will be used. For example a property of type NodaTime.LocalDateTime can be converted to and from a string using custom methods.

In db4o, `IObjectConstructor` would act as a similar translation layer to convert a type to another before it is persisted (LocalDateTime could be converted to DateTime).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `JsConfig<T>.RawSerializeFn` and `JsConfig<T>.RawDeserializeFn` properties.

```
JsConfig<NodaTime.LocalDateTime>.RawSerializeFn = dateTime => { 
                                                      //your implemetation
                                                  } ;
```